# Dynamics 365 on premise exception Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, dynamics-365

Try to debug my console app from yesterday but no success. My script keep throwing:

**Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://xxxxxxx/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl&sdkversion=8.2'.**

**xxxxxxx is place holder for my crm domain.**

I m using Dynamics 365 on premise version 1612(8.2.0.749)(DB 8.2.0.749). The Dynamics 365 was IFD.

To create console app,  I already,

1) Using latest dynamics  365 Sdk version 8.2.1.1 [Microsoft Dynamics 365 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50032)

2) Yeah, also install this sdk into my GAC. Then reboot my server.

3) To check wether my organization service endpoint is correct, I also paste my OrganizationService endpoint address `https://xxxxxxx/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc` in browser and its working by return the service.**

4) I m using Visual studio 2013, .net framework 4.5.2

weird things when using Dynamics 365 online trial its working fine.

This is my sample code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            IOrganizationService organizationservice;
            // Get the CRM connection string and connect to the CRM Organization

            ClientCredentials Credentials = new ClientCredentials();
            Credentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
            Credentials.UserName.Password = "password";

            Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

            organizationservice = new OrganizationServiceProxy(
                new Uri("https://xxxxxxx/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc"), null, Credentials, null);

        }
```

Exception throw:
[image: Exception throw:]

Details:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
HResult=-2146233079
Message=Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 
'https://xxxxxxx/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl&sdkversion=8.2'.
Source=System.ServiceModel
StackTrace:
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient.MetadataRetriever.Retrieve(TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient.ResolveNext(ResolveCallState resolveCallState)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient.GetMetadata(MetadataRetriever retriever)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient.GetMetadata(Uri address, MetadataExchangeClientMode mode)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceMetadataUtility.RetrieveServiceEndpointMetadata(Type contractType, Uri serviceUri, Boolean checkForSecondary)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfiguration`1..ctor(Uri serviceUri, Boolean checkForSecondary)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceConfiguration..ctor(Uri serviceUri, Boolean enableProxyTypes, Assembly assembly)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateConfiguration[TService](Uri serviceUri, Boolean enableProxyTypes, Assembly assembly)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateConfiguration[TService](Uri serviceUri)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceProxy`1..ctor(Uri uri, Uri homeRealmUri, ClientCredentials clientCredentials, ClientCredentials deviceCredentials)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy..ctor(Uri uri, Uri homeRealmUri, ClientCredentials clientCredentials, ClientCredentials deviceCredentials)
   at ConsoleConnectToCRM.Program.Main(String[] args) in d:\CRM2015\SSIS\TestCRMConnection\TestCRMConnection\Program.cs:line 45
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
   InnerException: System.Net.WebException
   HResult=-2146233079
   Message=The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
   Source=System
   StackTrace:
        at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
        at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient.MetadataLocationRetriever.DownloadMetadata(TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
        at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient.MetadataRetriever.Retrieve(TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
   InnerException: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
        HResult=-2147467259
        Message=The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm
        Source=System
        ErrorCode=-2147467259
        NativeErrorCode=-2146893007
        StackTrace:
             at System.Net.SSPIWrapper.AcquireCredentialsHandle(SSPIInterface SecModule, String package, CredentialUse intent, SecureCredential scc)
             at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireCredentialsHandle(CredentialUse credUsage, SecureCredential& secureCredential)
             at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireClientCredentials(Byte[]& thumbPrint)
             at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.GenerateToken(Byte[] input, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Byte[]& output)
             at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.NextMessage(Byte[] incoming, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
             at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
             at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
             at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
             at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state)
             at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
             at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
             at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
             at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
             at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
             at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
             at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
        InnerException:
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can leverage Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn689019.aspx

Comment: Thanks, Ok, I am aware that Microsoft.Xrm.Client.dll is deprecated, yet still can be used. Weird thing is when I run my console App in CRM server using the same code as above its working fine. However Its return a same exception when run inside DB server. I'm thinking there are wrong somewhere in my DB server. WEIRD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurs when the client computer cannot send an HTTP request. The client computer cannot send the HTTP request because the connection has been closed or is unavailable. And Today I realize that My DB server was using `TLS1.2` not `SSL` as a protocol to connect to CRM App Server, so when making a connection from DB to CRM via `console app`, I must explicitly set the TLS version on the ServicePointManager. Just have this code run anytime before you make the call to CRM organization service.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

Hope this will benefit someone in future.

Answer (score 1):

When I upgraded an application to CRM365, I had to change the way a connection was made. This is what I'm using

```
string crmConnectionString = $@"Url=https://<domain>;
    AuthType=Office365;
    UserName=<username>;
    Password=" + <password>;
CrmServiceClient crmSvcClient = new CrmServiceClient(crmConnectionString);
OrganizationServiceProxy proxy = crmSvcClient.OrganizationServiceProxy;
proxy.EnableProxyTypes();
OrganizationServiceContext orgContext = new OrganizationServiceContext(proxy);
```

This is not on premise, so I'm not positive it will work. But the connection string must specify the AuthType, and you need to use the CrmServiceClient for the connection.

Comment: Thanks Steve, yeah for Online version its working. I tried with on premise, but to no avail. I suspected there are something wrong in my DB server cause in CRM there was no such problem for console app to run.

Answer (score 0):

We have used IServiceManagement for crm version 2011 and upwards. An example in F# is shown below - which translates almost directly into C#.

```
let authenticate uri username password domain =
  let m = ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateManagement<IOrganizationService(uri)
  let cred = AuthenticationCredentials()
  cred.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential <- 
    new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain)
  let ac = m.Authenticate(cred)
  let proxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(m, ac.ClientCredentials)
  proxy.ServiceConfiguration.CurrentServiceEndpoint.Behaviors.Add(new ProxyTypesBehavior());
  proxy
```

Comment: Thanks, dont think the way of setup a connection cause the problem here. I'm worried there is something wrong in my DB server, cause using the same code for Console app in my CRM server, guess, its working fine.